# How long will roasted vegetables in oil keep in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, vegetables, storage-lifetime

[This recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aa3gTkJb8iQ&t=1m40s) says roasted tomato and garlic, put in a jar and covered in olive oil will keep for weeks in the fridge

[StillTasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18527) says 3-5 days

[This guide](https://www.csiro.au/en/Research/Health/Food-safety/Vegetable-preservation) says olive oil can only prevent discoloration/oxidation but not spoilage/toxicity/botulism

What am I missing?

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers on the topic you present.  It's hard to suggest an exact duplicate, because you raise multiple issues, but use the search bar and look at the related links on the right.  Short answer is cooked food in fridge = 3-5 days.  You are missing the fact that your three links refer to different situations/ingredients. In general, lack of oxygen is favorable for botulism (covered in oil).  Acidity (tomato, for example) and cold (refrigeration) mitigate the risk.

Comment: I am closing as another question which asks why there is a contradiction between food safety rules. In this case it isn't between two agencies, but between official FDA guidelines (with which Still Tasty is congruent) and the recipe author's claim. I know the OP wants to hear which is the "correct" shelf life, but that doesn't exist, all we have (and can have) about safety is merely different agencies' and people's opinions, and it is up to everybody to decide whether to trust the official guidelines or other people's gut feelings.